# How to change the error message of the Unique() validator of wtforms_components?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

When using the `Unique()` validator of wtforms_components (with Flask and SQLAlchemy), the default error message that shows up in the form is "Already exists". How can I change this error message as easy as I can change the error message of the `DataRequired()` validator?

---

The error message of the `DataRequired()` validator can be changed like this:

```
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class SignupForm():
    email = EmailField('Email', validators=[DataRequired('THIS IS MY NEW ERROR MESSAGE.')])
```

This changes the default error message from "This is required." to "THIS IS MY NEW ERROR MESSAGE." I am looking for a similarly simple and elegant solution for changing the default error message of the `Unique()` validator of wtforms_components

---

I was hoping that there is something like the following. However, it does not work:

```
from wtforms_components import Unique

  class SignupForm():
        email = EmailField('Email', validators=[Unique(User.email, get_session=lambda: db.session, 'THIS IS MY NEW ERROR MESSAGE.')])
```

The way, the validator is normally works (with the default error message) is as follows:

```
from wtforms_components import Unique

  class SignupForm():
        email = EmailField('Email', validators=[Unique(User.email, get_session=lambda: db.session)])
```

---

I am using the following packages:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-WTF==0.9.5
WTForms-Components==0.9.7
```

---

I did not find a solution in the WTForms-Alchemy documentation (http://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html). Also, I did not find a solution in the WTForms-Components documentation (http://wtforms-components.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#unique-validator). There was no solution in this forum either.

Thanks a lot for your hints in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the `Unique()` function clearly shows that there is a 3rd parameter called `message` that you pass as the error message. (Which is what you seem to be doing.)

https://github.com/kvesteri/wtforms-alchemy/blob/master/wtforms_alchemy/validators.py

> ```
> class Unique(object):
>     """Checks field values unicity against specified table fields.
>     :param column:
>         InstrumentedAttribute object, eg. User.name, or
>         Column object, eg. user.c.name, or
>         a field name, eg. 'name' or
>         a tuple of InstrumentedAttributes, eg. (User.name, User.email) or
>         a dictionary mapping field names to InstrumentedAttributes, eg.
>         {
>             'name': User.name,
>             'email': User.email
>         }
>     :param get_session:
>         A function that returns a SQAlchemy Session. This parameter is not
>         needed if the given model supports Flask-SQLAlchemy styled query
>         parameter.
>     :param message:
>         The error message.
>     """
>     field_flags = ('unique', )
>
>     def __init__(self, column, get_session=None, message=None):
>         self.column = column
>         self.message = message
>         self.get_session = get_session
> ```

I'm suggesting you may have some other issue- what is the error that you are getting as well as the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, shumuels! I had not specified the key **message=** and that is why it was not working. I will go through the source code on Github in the future if I don't find answers in the documentation.

```
from wtforms_components import Unique

  class SignupForm():
        email = EmailField('Email', validators=[Unique(User.email, get_session=lambda: db.session, message='THIS IS MY NEW ERROR MESSAGE.')])
```